# JSP page import 'The import cannot be resolved'

Tags: java, jsp

I have a java web project where the WEB-INF is as follows:

[image]

I am trying to import the classes in jsp like so:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*,javax.sql.*,javax.naming.*,logger.CMSLogger,java.io.*,utils.filter,java.text.SimpleDateFormat,utils.ConnectionPoolEsource,utils.PropertyReaderExternal,java.util.ArrayList,java.util.HashMap,java.util.Set,java.util.Iterator" errorPage="error1.jsp"  %>
```

However, Eclipse gives an error

> - The import logger cannot be resolved
> - The import utils cannot be resolved

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because eclipse is not able to find `logger.CMSLogger` and `utils.filter` in build path. Please add the relevant libraries (right-click your project >> Build Path >> Configure build path >> Libraries) and try again. If you are using maven, make sure your pom.xml has entry for these libraries and then right-click your project >> Maven >> Update Project ...

Comment: Thanks. The option was "Add Class Folder" inside Libraries

Comment: @Monty Swanson, also note that you don't typically want to have your Java source code inside the resultant web application as can be seen on the screenshot you supplied. You better put it in a separate source folder at the root of your project, name it e. g. "src", or "src/main/java" in the case of a Maven-based project.

Comment: @PetrBodnár I understand. It's an old code written by another developer. I'm simply trying to get it complied correctly so that I can deploy it on a new server.

Comment: OK, understood.